# CygWin > rTorrent > installing libTorrent (autogen.sh > aclocal not found)

Tags: cygwin

I was following rTorrent on windows installation instructions.. 
http://rtwi.jmk.hu/wiki/rTorrentOnWindows

..and i need help.

**Installing libTorrent**
[./autogen.sh](https://github.com/rakshasa/libtorrent/blob/master/autogen.sh)

When executing autogen.sh command, i get error 
aclocal...
aclocal not found

^Don't make funny of this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9):

> aclocal not found

aclocal is part of automake package. install automake on cygwin

Not a direct answer, but a workaround:

If you need a command line torrent client for windows, use aria2: http://aria2.sourceforge.net/

If you're looking for an open source client for windows, you have transmission and qbittorrent

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/trqtw/
- http://www.qbittorrent.org/

Comment: Nope, i am looking only for RuTorrent, yet can't figure out that "aclocal not found". What did i miss?

Comment: I've edited my answer. :) try installing the automake package in cygwin

Answer (score 4):

The program 'aclocal' can be found in the following packages:

- automake
- automake1.10
- automake1.4
- automake1.9
- automake1.7

Install like this:

```
wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg
install apt-cyg /bin
apt-cyg install automake
```